# Permission on specific instances of a model

Tags: django, permissions

I've got a CustomUser model with an additional field `region` and other models with this same field.

How can I allow an instance of CustomUser to add/delete/view instances of the other models (give all permissions) with the same region value only?

**EDIT**

Using a custom Manager, as suggested by vivek soundrapandi, I can do

```
class ShopManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ShopManager, self).get_query_set().filter(region=?)
```

but how can I filter the Shop instances by the region of the currently connected user?

And this still allow the CustomUser to modify Shop instances from other region using the default Manager, right?

There is no way to do it using Django permission system?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) (actually that's it, but SO wants more characters)

Comment: It seems that I must set a permission for every object. Is there any way to set a permission once for all the instances with a given value for a field, even those not created yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try using your own functions using model managers.
[click here for docs explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance)

OK,

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__exact='Beatles Blog')
```

This example retrieves all Entry objects with a Blog whose name is 'Beatles Blog'. So, your model manager should just perform the same for all the other classes that you want to refer to and combine them to produce a single result set.If i have understood your problem correct,this should be the solution.